# Finding a private method in a Base Class via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I find my method "button_Click" by name? If I make it public, it works, but I would rather have it private.

```
class Test : BaseTest
{
    public Test()
    {
        LoadMethod();
    }
}

class BaseTest
{
    public void LoadMethod()
    {
        //WHY IS THIS NULL???
        var eventMethod = GetType().GetMethod("button_Click", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }

    void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}
```

Comment: [XY Problem..](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Sayse: While there might be a different problem to solve, the question as stated is pretty self-contained and answerable.

Comment: I have posted what I attempted, which I figure should work, at least in some form.  I also stated my problem.  If there is an alternative solution, I am all ears.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Fair enough, but isn't that the whole xy problem point? It would just be solving a problem whlst covering up the underlying issue

Comment: @Sayse: Well normally it would be something hinting at a completely different problem - you could say that almost *any* question on SO is an XY problem in that case, unless the OP provides the complete big picture, business justification etc. I see nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 6):

> Why is `GetMethod` returning null?

Because the run-time type isn't of type `BaseTest`, it's of type `Test`, and `Test` doesn't define a method called `button_Click` (as it is `private` in your base class).

If you'd split the `GetType()` call and run your debugger, you'll see that the returned type is of type `Test`.

If you call `GetType().BaseType`, then you actually look at `BaseTest`:

```
var baseType = GetType().BaseType;
if (baseType != null)
{
    var eventMethod = baseType.GetMethod("button_Click", BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                                         BindingFlags.Instance);
}
```

Comment: the BindingFlags.NonPublic says that non-public members will be included in the search.  Test has a non-public member called button_Click

Comment: No, it doesn't. `BaseTest` does.

Comment: You could also change the method to be protected instead of private, then the reflection call finds the method defined on the parent class.